# Keep getting routing error on pin_image

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a newbie to coding and have been using SO to look for this answer. People have the same error but I can't figure out how it relates to my problem.

I'm working on a Pinterest clone but I keep getting this error in the command line when I add pictures. `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/pin_images/original/missing.png"):`

How would I add it to the routes? I thought it would already be allowed 
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :pins
  devise_for :users
  root 'home#index'

get 'new/pins'

# For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end

Comment: what do you get when you run command `rake routes` from the project directory?

Comment: it seems to be working now but i have a new problem `undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: probably if you use Devise then you have somewhere `current_user.username` or `@user.username` .. And that could be triggering the Error, because that variable (@user or current_user) is not valorized (has value nil). Maybe you are trying to print out on the screen or use the username, before the user is logged in. I am guessing, because you have no code hear. Please upload the code and Update your answer if some new issues come out. It is difficult otherwise to help. Thanks Fabrizio

Comment: like this 
{ class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find_by username: params[:username]
  end

end}

Comment: Can you help by looking at my github? https://github.com/timmparsons/sportworld